# JAVA: Call class method based on value of variable

Tags: java, object, switch-statement

I am working on a project in java and am quite new to the language and OOP. My dilema is that I want to carry out a task/function from a specific class based on the value of a variable.

This is kind of what I am trying to achieve.

```
class mainClass{

    String option;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainClass main = new mainClass();
    }

    mainClass(){
        secondClass sC = new secondClass();
        thirdClass tC = new thirdClass();
        switch (option){
            case "1" :
                sC.doSomething();
            case "2" :
                tC.doSomething();
        }
    }

}

class secondClass{
    void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("1");
    }


}

class thirdClass{
   void doSomething(){
       System.out.println("2");
   }

}
```

The reason I don't want to do this, is because if I want to add a fourth, fifth, sixth class  etc... I would have to update the switch.

I tried using a hashmap. Where I assigned secondClass the key of "1". But then I would have to cast the object, but this brings me back to the original headache of not knowing what class would need to be called in advance.

So then I tried using a hashmap like this,
`HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();`

Which I could then do map.get("1") but then now I can't call any of the methods for the class in question.

If I need to use a large switch statement I will, but I am actively seeking a more efficient alternative.

Comment: interfaces, inheritance and method overriding - learn them.

Comment: If they're all going to have a `doSomething()` method, why not have them all extend a common base class, or implement a common interface? Also, you need `break;` statements in your `switch`.

Comment: Yeah I know it was just a quick mock up of the sort of thing I was looking for. The reason for not having them extend doSomething() is because doSomething() is different in each instance. Thanks @james I will look in to overriding! I'd thought about inheritance but like I stated earlier, each doSomething() method is different.

Comment: I was going to answer, but the more I think about this, it feels like a homework assignment.  Can you ask your TA or teacher if you are lost?  I think that's the best answer.  (And if this isn't homework, then you need to explain better, your example is much too simple.)

Comment: You might look at the Strategy Design Pattern

Comment: @Adam.J That's irrelevant as long as their name and signature remain the same.

Comment: It's not homework, I'm 22 and learning java as a hobby.

Comment: @mickey - why did you suggest the strategy design pattern ?

Comment: @AdamJ:  Even worse!  Seriously, take an online class or enroll at a community college.  A lot of this stuff is too complicated to learn (properly!) from random online people.

Comment: Please don't discourage anyone to learn something new. You can abstain to help if you feel the question is too trivial.

Comment: I had to take an online course to learn Java.  It helped quite a bit;  I consider it to be the correct answer, and not at all unfriendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to use a `Map` but you were also right to balk at casting. However, nowadays with generics you can get around all that:

```
interface DoesSomething {
    // An object implementing this interface does something.
    public void doSomething();
}

// Class that does something.
class FirstClass implements DoesSomething {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // What FirstClass does.
    }

}

// Another class that does something.
class SecondClass implements DoesSomething {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // What SecondClass does.
    }

}


// How I know what to do. Map the string to a DoesSomethng.
Map<String, DoesSomething> whatToDo = new HashMap<>();
{
    // Populate my map.
    whatToDo.put("1", new FirstClass());
    whatToDo.put("2", new SecondClass());
}

public void doSomethingDependingOnSomething(String something) {
    // Look up the string in the map.
    DoesSomething toDo = whatToDo.get(something);
    // Was it in there?
    if (toDo != null) {
        // Yes! Make it do it's thing.
        toDo.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL I checked if `containsKey` was a better way to check it (since semantics imply that) and it turns out that `HashMap` implements `containsKey` as `return get(key) != null;`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's exactly what I was looking for. I'm reading up about interfaces and overrides as we speak! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using Reflection (wich is discouraged here), you should consider a simple SAM-Interface:

```
public interface Doable { public void doSomething(); }
```

and have all classes implement the interface (no other changes required in these classes) and having a `Map<String, Doable>` and calling

```
if (map.containsKey(option)) map.get(option).doSomething();

// Or (may be a little faster)
Doable opt = map.get(option);
if (opt != null) opt.doSomething();
```

If your implementations have different methods, you'll most likely be bound to use [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to get the declared methods and compare by String.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try! Appreciate it.

Comment: I'd still like to see a better example, closer to what you are really doing.  There's a lot of ways to do this, and even more ways to do it wrong.  I think get some advice on your design as well as the coding would help you more.